# MATLAB : how to change .txt data

Tags: matlab

i have a problem in matlab. hello all. i need help.here is my code. how do i change the data in my .txt file ? when **a-b** meet my condition i want to change it in both .txt file. i keep getting error. im using matlab and really new in matlab. please help me. thank you

```
a = dlmread('test4.txt');
b = dlmread('test5.txt');
if (a-b)>125
   c = (a-b)>125;
   c = 0;
   c = dlmmwrite('test4.txt', f, 'delimiter', ',');
   c = dlmwrite('test5.txt', f, 'delimiter', ',');
end
```

Comment: What do you want to change both values to should they meet this condition?  You're doing `c = a - b > 125` then `c = 0`, so you're overwriting what `c` is.  Please further improve your post by putting in example inputs and outputs.

Comment: You probably want `if (a-b)>125` and `c = (a-b)>125;`. What you have written is equivalent to `if a-(b>125)`, which is probably not  what you want.

Comment: @rayryeng. im overwriting c ? what is the correct way to write it sir ? sorry for my english.

Comment: Look at the first two lines of your code inside the if statement. What are you doing there? The variable c keeps getting replaced.

Comment: @rayryeng im trying to set the variable c to zero after it meet the if condition. is it wrong sir ?

Comment: @rayryeng i try this code also doesnt work. why the value in the text file doesnt change ?

Comment: @rayryeng **a = dlmread('test4.txt');
b = dlmread('test5.txt');
c =(a-b)>125; % Logical array
a(c) = 0; % Replace elements in a with 0;
b(c) = 0; % Replace elements in b with 0;
% Write updated a and b back out.
dlmwrite('test4.txt', a);
dlmwrite('test5.txt', b);**

Comment: @am304 thank you sir. but how can i change the data in .txt file ? i already try the code above send by friend but the value in text file still not change. why ?

Comment: @AkmalRahmat - That code should work... the one in your comments.  I would have written the same thing.... I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with @rayryeng, the code in the comments should work.